# Groups using regular expression in Bash on windows

Tags: regex, windows, bash

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
message=“TIME-1 TIME-2 test"
echo $message | sed -E 's/(^([A-Z]{2,8}-[0-9]{1,4}).*[[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]]+$).*$/\2/‘
```

Gives:  TIME-1

Should give: TIME-1 TIME-2

I need it working on windows, linux and macos (as part of git hook), so cannot use “=~"

Can somebody please correct what I am wrong at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this does what you ask:

```
$ echo "$message" | sed -E 's/(^([A-Z]{2,8}-[0-9]{1,4}[[:space:]]+)*).*/\1/'
TIME-1 TIME-2
```

Comment: Thanks. Works as expected.